# After reboot debian box ignore sysctl.conf values

Tags: linux, debian, sysctl, debian-wheezy

Where is right place for sysctl redefined values?

I have:

```
> uname -a
Linux note 3.1.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Tue Jan 10 05:01:58 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

> cat /etc/debian_version 
wheezy/sid


> tail -n 2 /etc/sysctl.conf   
#
net.ipv6.bindv6only=0
```

But after each reboot net.ipv6.bindv6only still 1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check if there is a file in /etc/sysctl.d with your parameter. These files override the /etc/sysctl.conf file...

Comment: yep. i found /etc/sysctl.d/bindv6only.conf thanks

Comment: /etc/sysctl.d/README states the precedence order and specifically "use /etc/sysctl.conf directly, which overrides anything in this directory." Is the README wrong?

Comment: If you have a recent Debian, it load the /etc/sysctl.conf at the last one (see 99-sysctl.conf file). This topic is for old Debian (before 2014). In the new versions, the files must have a number to know the order to use.

Comment: @Dom i am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS . Still it not taking  /etc/sysctl.conf neighter 99-sysctl.conf as precedence file. anything still missing?

Comment: Check the syntax of the files. They should be used. In 16.04, the files must have a XX- and .conf at the end. Try to restart procps service and look at logs, it can be an error

Comment: Note that in RHEL, "sysctl --system" and "systemd-sysctl.service" apply the directories in different orders.  Perhaps systemd inherited init.d's ordering.  I do think that "sysctl --system" applies things in the wrong order, /etc/sysctl.d/* (at least) should come after /etc/sysctl.conf, and the "defaults" (/lib/sysctl.d) should be much earlier in the sequence.  This forces us to be aware of the numbering of all of the files (version-dependent?), or to edit sysctl.conf, which is far more error-prone than dropping a new file in whatever sysctl.d is processed at the right time.

Comment: @stolenmoment I think it's a similar **braindead** situation in Debian 11 - `/etc/sysctl.d/99-local.conf` is overwritten by e.g. `/lib/sysctl.d/protect-links.conf`, so it's needed to use `/etc/sysctl.d/zz-local.conf` instead.

Answer (score 16):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/procps/+bug/50093

`/etc/init.d/procps.sh` comes too early in the boot process to apply a lot of sysctl's. As it runs before networking modules are loaded and filesystems are mounted, there are quite a lot of commonly-used sysctl's which are simply ignored on boot and produce errors to the console.

All documentation on the net referring to changing certain settings in /etc/sysctl.conf such as `net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max` is wrong for Ubuntu & Debian.

Finally, "It seems to me it is a Debian Squeeze bug, see here for an example and workaround:
http://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections

> In the latter case, the procps init script should take care of loading
>   them during boot. However, on Squeeze it does not, and you need to
>   restart it from /etc/rc.local (or similar):
>
> ```
> # /etc/rc.local
>
> # Load kernel variables from /etc/sysctl.d
> /etc/init.d/procps restart
>
> exit 0
> ```

Answer (score 7):

If you use **ufw** (uncomplicated firewall) you really need to change the values in `/etc/ufw/sysctl.conf` as the configuration here **overrides** `/etc/sysctl.conf one`.

Comment: Thank you. But no, i did not use ufw. Problem was solved, data was redefined in /etc/sysctl.d

Comment: Damn I was pulling my hair on this for hours. I thought it was issue 50093, but this was it. Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: 8 years later this is still relevant.  Confirmed to be the case on Ubuntu server 20.04 running UFW

Answer (score 0):

This is set by the procps init script.  make sure this init script is enabled with `update-rc.d procps enable`.  If it is enabled you should expect a link from a file in /etc/rcS.d to /etc/init.d/procps.  If this init script is working correctly manually running `/etc/init.d/procps restart` should make the setting.

Comment: You mean Debian doesn't read sysctl.conf by default? _wow_.

Comment: it reads sysctl by default. the /etc/init.d/procps mecahnism is the default mechanism.  If my answer works, it is because this init script was disabled for some reason, which might be a bug.  A bug causing this would not be surprising since he is running either the testing or unstable release of debian (or some combination thereof)

Comment: > sysctl net.ipv6.bindv6only  
net.ipv6.bindv6only = 1 

doesnt works